# Confused why JavaScript Bundling breaks in Web Forms ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, bundle

I'm working on an application where a previous developer loaded the same script file across many different pages.

```
<script src="../scripts/helpers.js"></script>
```

Now I'm trying to load that into the `BundleConfig.cs` file so it's accessible throughout the site and not referenced on every page.  I also have `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/helpers")
    .Include("~/scripts/helpers.js"));
```

In the `Site.Master` I'm referencing it (currently in the head, but have tried several places in the body as well) as:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/helpers") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

When I look at the network tab in the Chrome console, it shows that it bundled the file, but none of the functionality is working.  I can't seem to figure out why it's working when called on every page, but not when it's bundled once and always there.  This is the first time I've worked on a .NET app, so I have definitely been scratching my head on this one.

Comment: What is the output html and what did you expect to get? That is in the loaded bundled javascript file?

Comment: It's to show and hide a side navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it works this way, mostly because I'm not familiar with ASP.NET.  But referencing it in the script manager made it work.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" >
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/bundles/helpers" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```